# Replacing the primary SSD of a Plug and Play System

Tags: ssd, plug-and-play

I got a special problem here and need some advice.
Two days ago i bought a HP Omen Plug'n'Play Gaming PC with a WD Black SSD as primary. I thougt they will installed a flagship like WD Black SN850 or anything, so it will be better than the SSD from my old Workhorse PC, where i got a Firecuda 520. But surprise, HP didn't spend too much money on the primary and according to AS SSD Benchmark it's half that fast than the Firecuda.
Furthermore, on the Omen Gaming PC there's Win11 Home preinstalled and on the Firecuda System is Win11 Pro installed.
So long so clear.

Does anybody have an advice on how to swap the two SSD's? And is it even possible to transfer the  Win11 Pro License to the gaming Rig?

Or just an advice on the best Cloning Freeware out there.

Thanks and Cheers

Comment: You can put the other SSD in your computer and simply reinstall Windows 11. It will activate just fine. The process will set up the proper partitions. I have done this numerous times. Asking the best cloning software is off topic.

Comment: You cannot transfer OEM (supplied by PC manufacturer) licences between PCs.